# Trying to reset a whirlpool washing machine wwdc 6400/1 (front loading)

Tags: washing-machine

My washing machine start button broke and my neighbour popped in to have a look and fix it (the day after I had come back home from an emergency operation so I was very out of it) he has replaced and fixed the button but in taking the washing machine apart he removed the control unit, it has all been wired back correctly but various lights are flashing including the service light. Looking online it seems that the Control Unit needs a rest but I can't work out how to do that, any suggestions?

Comment: Pressing power button for 3 ~ 10 seconds does not work? Just guessing as it is a standard way to reset across most of the devices.

Comment: Unplugging it and plugging it back in should reset it...I can't believe it would have anything stored in internal memory that needs to be actively reset.   More likely the connectors on the controller aren't seated properly.

Comment: Thanks all think it is somehow very broke, went out and bought a new washing machine in the end yesterday. Lesson learnt, don't let someone anywhere near anythign when the say they can have a look and try. And don't agree to anything when recovering from general Anasthetic lol